# Passing a timestamp from Databricks to Snowflake SQL not working from Databricks

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I have a snowflake query as below.

```
SELECT * FROM test CHANGES(INFORMATION => DEFAULT) AT(TIMESTAMP => '2023-05-03 00:43:34.885 -7000')
```

I am passing a tablename and timestamp dynamically from Databrikcs. Snowflake and Databricks both have same region enabled and passing same time format as well.
Query is forming correctly but not working in Databrikcs same is working in snowflake. Change Tracking enabled on test table.

Below is my code.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_utc_timestamp
df = spark.read.format("snowflake").options(**options).option("query","SELECT DATEADD( minute, -240, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) as lastruntime").load()
display(df)

df = df.withColumn("lastruntime", from_utc_timestamp("lastruntime", "America/Los_Angeles"))
df = df.withColumn("lastruntime", date_format("lastruntime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS -7000"))
rows = df.collect()
lastruntime = str(rows[0][0])

readquery = f"SELECT * FROM {table}  CHANGES(INFORMATION => DEFAULT) AT(TIMESTAMP => '%s')" %lastruntime
print(readquery)
df = spark.read.format("snowflake").options(**options).option("query", readquery).load()
```

Below is the error I am getting.

`net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: Time travel data is not available for table TEST. The requested time is either beyond the allowed time travel period or before the object creation time.`

May I know what the problem could be here while passing a time using Databricks.

Comment: Just based on the error message, does it mean that the passed timestamp is older than the allowed time travel period or before the table was created ? - can you maybe try giving a timestamp that is closer ? maybe hard code a timestamp (current timestamp -1hour) just to check ?

Comment: The error you are getting is not related necessarily to the timestamp value only.
Enabling change tracking is not enough to run CHANGES queries. You also need the table history for the full interval for which you are requesting changes. The retention of table history is configured using [DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters#data-retention-time-in-days).

Comment: but the same thing is working in Snowflake, The same select statement is not working from Databricks. If Rention time is the problem that should not work snowflake side as well I think.

Comment: rainingdistros- Current timestamp also I passed not working from Databricks.

Comment: To clarify timezone settings can you provide from Databricks: `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, `spark.conf.get("spark.sql.session.timeZone")`, from Snowflake: `show parameters like '%timezone%';`?